# Span Icon align in Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, datetimepicker

I am new in bootstrap 3 and I am start trying to learn. Now I am facing the alignment problem.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result is => [image]

Why span icon is align right? How can I fix this? Is this because of `"col-md-9"`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using `bootstrap.css` v. 3.3.7, check your custom css.

Comment: Currently my bootstrap js and css  version is  v.3.0.0

Comment: @John If you have used any styling please upload

Answer (score 2):

I think you could start learning from [Bootstrap v3.3.7](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) or [Bootstrap v4.1.1](https://getbootstrap.com/), also this guideline could be very helpful [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I hope this will be helpful:

**Generic Responsive solution**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- use the related col class according with your needs eg. col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Some inline style for the label -->
        <label style="float: left; padding-top: 5px; margin-right: 20px">Date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**input-group with a hypothetical fixed width of 200px solution**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- Some inline style for the label -->
      <label style="float: left; padding-top: 5px; margin-right: 20px">Date</label>
      <!-- input-group with an hypothetical fixed width of 200px -->
      <div class="input-group date" style="width: 200px;" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not correct. Try reducing the width of the textbox like it is shown in the problem

Comment: @Arex it is working fine for me. Did you use exactly my code as per above?

Comment: Add style="width:200px;" to input tag. In problem we have a specific width of input

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but was it specified in your example?

Comment: Oh I see, to be honest I think that the image is not just enough to understand that he has got a width of 200px. However I will try to provide a different solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174077/discussion-between-arex-and-matt).